# Delegates with explicit "this" pointer?

Tags: .net, delegates

Is it possible to adapt a method like this function "F"

```
class C {
    public void F(int i);
}
```

to a delegate like `Action<C,int>`?

I have this vague recollection that Microsoft was working on supporting this kind of adaptation. But maybe I misremembered!

**Edit**: I know that this doesn't compile in VS2008:

```
class C {
    public void F(int i);
    void G() {
        Action<C, int> test = this.F;
    }
}
```

I was just wondering if MS provides a way to do this in the BCL, or if the feature would be added in a future version.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by this? What will it accomplish that `var test = new Action<int>(this.F)` can't?

Comment: The difference is that you could change the instance of class C every time you call the delegate.

Comment: Here's a nice blog post on open delegates: http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2010/07/28/93676.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to create a lambda which takes a `C` and an `int`, and calls `F` on the `C`, passing the `int`:

```
Action<C, int> test = (c, v) => c.F(v);
```

You can also create what's called an *open* delegate to the instance method `C.F`, as opposed to the usual type of delegate which is "closed over it's instance parameter". This would be done using reflection and the [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6.aspx) method. While that would result in a more 'direct' delegate, it is in all likelihood more complex than you require.

Comment: This "open delegate" is precisely what I wanted. The lambda solution isn't bad, but theoretically should be slower, and I wanted the maximum possible performance (I was generating code at run-time so avoiding the complexity of reflection would be impossible either way). Since this question wasn't answered for a long time, I ended up taking a very different approach than I initially envisioned.